# Background Task самопроизвольное завершение в c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, background-task

Создаю фоновую задачу таким образом:

```
   string myTaskName = "Task";

   foreach (var cur in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
        if (cur.Value.Name == myTaskName)
        {
           return;
        }

   await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();

   BackgroundTaskBuilder taskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder 
   { 
        Name = "Task", 
        TaskEntryPoint = "Background.Task"
   };
   taskBuilder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, true));
   BackgroundTaskRegistration myFirstTask = taskBuilder.Register();
```

Сама таска создается в Windows Runtime Component как отдельный класс:

```
 public sealed class Task : IBackgroundTask 
        {
            public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
            {
                BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

//логика таски, подключение к локальной базе данных, 
//отправка http get запроса на получение данных с сервера, обработка и сравнение данных

                deferral.Complete();
            }
}
```

Когда наступает время выполнения таски - она может выполнятся случайное количество раз,(1 - 5 раз) и потом самопроизвольно завершается и больше не запускается, приходится заново регистрировать таску. 
В чем может быть причина?
Возможно в том что я потребляю слишком много ресурсов телефона при срабатывании таски(переменные, массивы , строки и тд)?
Если да, то как их очищать после завершения работы таски, что бы на следующий запуск память освобождалась под новые переменные таски?

Лог после завершения таски:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ArgumentException возникает всегда, даже если таска просто зарегистрирована и пуста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему то прокатило и с 15 минутами, только oneshot должен быть false. Иначе снова не запускается.
Исправление  `taskBuilder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, true));`на  `taskBuilder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false));` дало результат.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977059.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Логично. Параметр `oneShot` отвечает за то, будет ли таск запущен один раз или будет запускаться периодически.

Comment: Верно подмечено

Answer (score 0):

На Телефоне есть ограничение на потребление Оперативной памяти.
Для телефона с RAM 500 Мб, приложение не может потреблять более 180 Мб, с RAM 1 Гб больше, но ориентироваться нужно на 180 Мб(реально в районе 160 Мб).
Отследить загрузку памяти можно Запустив "Отладка"->"Производительность и диагностика"
Если вылет приложения происходит по вине памяти, то тут или ищите утечки, либо думайте над разделением данных при обработке. Но 180 Мб, при отсутствии утечки, довольно достаточно для телефона.

Но вы описали что завершается только Task'а, а это непохоже на вылет приложения при превышения предела использования памяти. Т.к. в этом случае закрывается полностью само приложение, а не отдельная Task'а.

Comment: Дело в том когда я в выполняющейся таске вставляю просто debug.writeln() то вылеты не прекращаются, возможно как то не правильно таску регистрирую? То есть пределы памяти не превышены. Причина в чем то другом
Да именно так, закрывается сама таска